# Parsing Real-Time Changing text by Javascript

Tags: javascript, sql, parsing, real-time, data-mining

I would like to parse a webpage to gather data for scientific use. The text I need to parse is located within a < span >. Parsing the HTML will not achieve this because this text is constantly changing, sometimes as fast as 10 updates each second. I know for a fact (due to a scientific paper I read) that it is possible.

The webpage I need to gather the data from : http://realtime.springer.com/map
Basically, each time the paper is downloaded, the marker is shown on the map. I am looking to data-mine the city/location for each marker in real-time as they pop up which you can see under the map on the left side.

Questions:
1) How can I parse this real-time changing text since it is being generated by java-script code? Parsing webpages isn't a subject that is so new to me but real-time changing text is.

2) Since speed is an issue here in parsing & writing the data, which language would be best for my project? I plan on writing to a SQL database since speed is very much an issue, so keep in mind the entire operation as well as the ease at which it can be done when considering each language. I would like python if there are well documented libraries I can use.

Thank you very much in advance for any advice.

Comment: That page uses ajax to load the changing data. You could call that same ajax entry point to load that same data. I suspect that company won't want you to do that and may cut off your IP addresses if they notice. Just look at the page source and the JS.

Comment: Not sure if they care that much to block my IP. The authors of this scientific journal did the same thing I'm trying to do: http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1751157712000545

Answer (score 0):

It looks like they are making a JSON call to get the map data.  Assuming you have their permission (there is a copyright notice), you could call the same URL to get the raw data directly rather than parsing it from the map.

```
$.getJSON('/ip2location/lookupMulti.php', { "rand": Math.random() }, function(data) {
    for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
        var lat = data[i].lat;
        var lng = data[i].lng;
        var name = data[i].name;
    }
            // Etc...
```

Many companies have policies against pinging their server frequently (whether loading the main page or calling lookupMulti.php).  If you do not have permission, you may well find that your IP is quickly banned.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. The researcher in charge of this project will contact them and get permission.